# Scala compiler plugin to rewrite method calls

Tags: scala, plugins, compiler-construction

I'm trying to write a Scala compiler plugin that rewrites method calls from instantiating `Set` to instantiations of `LinkedHashSet`. Unfortunately I can't find any working example that does this already. The following code fails with `no-symbol does not have an owner`:

```
object DemoErasureComponent extends PluginComponent with TypingTransformers with Transform {
val global: DemoPlugin.this.global.type = DemoPlugin.this.global

import global._

override val runsAfter = List("erasure")

val phaseName = "rewrite-sets"

def newTransformer(unit: CompilationUnit) = new SetTransformer(unit)

class SetTransformer(unit: CompilationUnit) extends TypingTransformer(unit) {

  override def transform(tree: Tree): Tree = tree match {
    case a@Apply(r@Select(rcvr@Select(predef, set), name), args) if name.toString == "Set" =>
      localTyper.typed(treeCopy.Apply(tree, Ident(newTermName("LinkedHashSet")), args))

    case t => super.transform(tree)
  }
}
```

For the record, I've found these resources so far:

- Scalaxy compiler plugin: https://github.com/ochafik/Scalaxy
- Boxer compiler plugin example: [https://github.com/retronym/boxer](https://github.com/ochafik/Scalaxy)
- outdated compiler plugin inside the Scala compiler: [http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/docs/examples/plugintemplate/src/plugintemplate/TemplateTransformComponent.scala](https://github.com/ochafik/Scalaxy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
localTyper.typed(treeCopy.Apply(tree, Ident(newTermName("LinkedHashSet")), args))
```

Here, you are creating a new `Apply` node via a tree copy, which will copy the type and symbol from `tree`.

When you typecheck this node, the typer will not recurse into its children as it is already typed, so the `Ident` will pass through without a type and symbol, which will likely lead to a crash in the code generation phase.

Instead of creating an unattributed `Ident` and typechecking it, it is more customary to create a fully attrtibuted reference with of the utility methods in `TreeGen`.

```
gen.mkAttributedRef(typeOf[scala.collection.immutable.LinkedHashSet].typeSymbol)
```

The `case` is also pretty suspicious. You should never need to compare strings like that. It is always better to compare `Symbol`s.

Furthermore, you have to be aware of the tree shapes at the phase you're inserting your compiler plugin. Notice below how after typer, the tree is expanded to include the call to the `apply` method, and that after erasure, the variable arguments are wrapped in single argument.

```
% qscalac -Xprint:parser,typer,erasure sandbox/test.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // test.scala
package <empty> {
  object Test extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    Set(1, 2, 3)
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // test.scala
package <empty> {
  object Test extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Test.type = {
      Test.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    scala.this.Predef.Set.apply[Int](1, 2, 3)
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of                   erasure]] // test.scala
package <empty> {
  object Test extends Object {
    def <init>(): Test.type = {
      Test.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    scala.this.Predef.Set().apply(scala.this.Predef.wrapIntArray(Array[Int]{1, 2, 3}))
  }
}
```

Tracking down non-determinism that is caused by making assumptions about the iteration order of `HashMaps` can be a bit of a nightmare. But I'd caution against this sort of rewriting. If you want a policy within your system to say that non-determistic Sets and Maps should not be used, removing *direct* usages of them is insufficient. Every call to `.toSet` or `toMap` will end up using them anyway.

You might be better served to instrument the bytecode of the standard library (or use a patched standard library) in a test mode to catch *all* instantiations of these structures (perhaps logging a stack trace). Or, as a more fine grained alternative, find calls to place like `HashTrieSet#foreach` (although, you'll need to filter out benign usages like the call to `foreach` within `collection.immutable.HashSet(1, 2, 3).count(_ => true)`.

Comment: The line `typeOf[scala.collection.immutable.LinkedHashSet].typeSymbol` fails with: `[error] (main/compile:compile) scala.ScalaReflectionException: class demo.DemoErasureComponent in compiler mirror not found.` ... however, this seems to work: `rootMirror.getRequiredClass("scala.collection.mutable.Set")`... any idea what I'm doing wrong? I noticed that `typeOf` is not used in the continuations or any other compiler plugin that I checked...